# within .swift file, why are some func are not within the class bracket

Tags: ios, swift, func

let's say the file name is MessageBubbleCell.swift

```
class MessageBubbleCell: UITableViewCell {
...
}

func bubbleImageMake() -> 
(incoming: UIImage, incomingHighlighed: UIImage, outgoing: UIImage, outgoingHighlighed: UIImage) {...}
```

the context of the func is not an issue. I don't understand why some func are outside the boundaries of class {}. There are a few func within the class {}. So then whats the difference?

Comment: BTW your method written like that wouldn't accept any parameters and return 4. You can use inout in front of your parameters if you want to modify them. When calling the method you would need to add & in front of the vars (inout ones) when calling it

Comment: Check out this series on the iBooks Store:
“Swift Programming Series”
https://itun.es/us/D33-0.l

Comment: Check out this book on the iBooks Store:
“Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C” by Apple Inc.
https://itun.es/us/1u3-0.l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method that is defined within the class opening and closing braces is an *instance method* or a *type method* -

> You write an instance method within the opening and closing braces of
>   the type it belongs to. An instance method has implicit access to all
>   other instance methods and properties of that type. An instance method
>   can be called only on a specific instance of the type it belongs to.
>   It cannot be called in isolation without an existing instance.
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.”

You can also define *type methods* - these are called on the class itself, rather than on an instance. Type methods are defined with the `class` prefix (or `static` in the case of a struct) and accessed against the class name itself  `MyClass.createDefaultInstance()` as an example.

What you have in your question is a global method - This can be called from anywhere and without providing a context.  Personally I would have created it as type method as it provides functionality that is logically associated with the `MessageBubbleCell` class.

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus - Yeah, the syntax is wrong, but I figured the spirit of the question was about the placement of the definition, rather than the format :)